# How to convert lab frame quaternions and plane normal to misorientation quaternion and crystal plane normal for grain boundaries?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography, grain-boundaries

#### Background

Let `qA` and `qB` represent unit, orientation quaternions of grain A and grain B of a grain boundary in the lab reference frame, respectively. Let `qm` be the misorientation quaternion of `qA` and `qB`. Quaternion inversion (`qinv`) and quaternion multiplication (`qmult`) are discussed in [Quaternions and spatial rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). Let `mA` be the boundary plane normal pointing from grain A to grain B in the sample reference frame. Let `nA` be the boundary plane normal pointing outwards from grain A towards grain B in the grain A crystal reference frame. All boundary planes are represented in 3D Cartesian coordinates.

```matlab
qinv(qA) = [qA(1) -qA(2:4)]
qinv(qB) = [qB(1) -qB(2:4)]

qmult(qA,qB) ~= qmult(qB,qA) %non-commutative
```

#### My Understanding

I think the misorientation quaternion is obtained by one of the following two conversions:

1. `qm = qmult(qinv(qA),qB);`
2. `qm = qmult(qB,qinv(qA));`

I think the boundary plane normal is represented by:

```matlab
nA = qmult(qA,qmult([0 mA],qinv(qA)));
nA = nA(2:4); %drop 1st element which is 0
```

While the two misorientation quaternions share the same misorientation angle, they each represent rotations around different axes, and thus (as far as I understand), a different grain boundary.

#### Question

What is the appropriate conversion of (`qA`, `qB`, `mA`) triplets to (`qm`, `nA`) pairs?

#### References

DOI: [10.1088/0965-0393/23/8/083501](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0965-0393/23/8/083501)

Comment: +1. Welcome to our community and thank you so much for contributing your question here!! We hope to see much more of you here !!!

Comment: If there's a more appropriate stack exchange for this question, happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: I've posted it [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50925871#50925871) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56149637#56149637). One room is specifically for MATLAB and the other specifically for Physics. I worry that it still won't be enough. I don't know a lot of people that work a lot with quaternions. Many mathematicians know what they are, but I think might be unlikely to answer a question about grain-boundaries or crystallography. Perhaps you can explain in the above two chat rooms, some more details about what you want?

Comment: Hi Sterling, I added some `code` blocks to improve the formatting a bit, and this will have the positive effect of bumping the question up to the top so that more users can see it (now that we have a lot more users than when you first asked this question). I 
have a question: What exactly is the reference for? Typically a reference list would be added when there's in-line citations to the items in the reference list, [as in this case](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/86/5).

Comment: See https://github.com/sgbaird-5DOF/interp for my implementation, in particular: [qmA2five.m](https://github.com/sgbaird-5DOF/interp/blob/master/code/qmA2five.m)

Comment: Hi Sterling, do you want the question reopened? @Tyberius can do it. Do you have a self-answer that you can write now?

Comment: @Nike that's fine, I probably can't justify making a full answer right now, and it's resolved on my end. Just made the comment for completeness. Eventually, I may flesh out my comment into a full answer. Also, the relevant paper is https://doi.org/10.1016/j.commatsci.2021.110756, specifically Appendix A